# Get_Next_by_Date() gives back the name of the Post instead of it's url

Tags: django

I have a blog like application where I am trying to implement a NEXT button for each post of the Blog.
I am currently using Detail_View to display each individual post.

In the template, I am using

```
<a>href="{{post.get_next_by_date}}">NEXT</a>
```

but instead of the proper link to the next post, what I am having back is a link to the blog, with the name of the post instead of the PK, something like :

blog/name of the post xy

suggestions on how to solve the issue?
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
<a href="/blog/{{post.get_next_by_date.id}}/{{post.get_next_by_date.slug}}">NEXT BLOG PAGE</a>
```

It works with the generic view "detail_view"